# Smartcard Reader of Dell Latitude E7450 not recognized

Tags: drivers, 15.04, dell, smartcard

Recently I upgraded my "old" Dell Latitude E7440 to a newer E7450. Both include a SmartCard reader. Using Ubuntu 15.04, the reader in the E7440 was recognized and worked perfectly, which is however not the case for the reader in my new notebook. My USB reader works perfectly. Unfortunately I don't know which type of SmartCard reader was included in the E7440, and I do not have access anymore.

Some further information:

lsusb -v

```
Bus 003 Device 005: ID 0a5c:5804 Broadcom Corp. 
Couldn't open device, some information will be missing
Device Descriptor:
  bLength                18
  bDescriptorType         1
  bcdUSB               1.10
  bDeviceClass            0 (Defined at Interface level)
  bDeviceSubClass         0 
  bDeviceProtocol         0 
  bMaxPacketSize0        64
  idVendor           0x0a5c Broadcom Corp.
  idProduct          0x5804 
  bcdDevice            1.01
  iManufacturer           1 
  iProduct                2 
  iSerial                 3 
  bNumConfigurations      1
  Configuration Descriptor:
    bLength                 9
    bDescriptorType         2
    wTotalLength          269
    bNumInterfaces          4
    bConfigurationValue     0
    iConfiguration          0 
    bmAttributes         0xe0
      Self Powered
      Remote Wakeup
    MaxPower              100mA
    Interface Descriptor:
      bLength                 9
      bDescriptorType         4
      bInterfaceNumber        0
      bAlternateSetting       0
      bNumEndpoints           3
      bInterfaceClass       254 Application Specific Interface
      bInterfaceSubClass      0 
      bInterfaceProtocol      0 
      iInterface              4 
      ** UNRECOGNIZED:  10 25 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
      Endpoint Descriptor:
        bLength                 7
        bDescriptorType         5
        bEndpointAddress     0x81  EP 1 IN
        bmAttributes            2
          Transfer Type            Bulk
          Synch Type               None
          Usage Type               Data
        wMaxPacketSize     0x0040  1x 64 bytes
        bInterval               0
      Endpoint Descriptor:
        bLength                 7
        bDescriptorType         5
        bEndpointAddress     0x01  EP 1 OUT
        bmAttributes            2
          Transfer Type            Bulk
          Synch Type               None
          Usage Type               Data
        wMaxPacketSize     0x0040  1x 64 bytes
        bInterval               0
      Endpoint Descriptor:
        bLength                 7
        bDescriptorType         5
        bEndpointAddress     0x85  EP 5 IN
        bmAttributes            3
          Transfer Type            Interrupt
          Synch Type               None
          Usage Type               Data
        wMaxPacketSize     0x0010  1x 16 bytes
        bInterval              32
    Interface Descriptor:
      bLength                 9
      bDescriptorType         4
      bInterfaceNumber        1
      bAlternateSetting       0
      bNumEndpoints           3
      bInterfaceClass        11 Chip/SmartCard
      bInterfaceSubClass      0 
      bInterfaceProtocol      0 
      iInterface              5 
      ChipCard Interface Descriptor:
        bLength                54
        bDescriptorType        33
        bcdCCID              1.00
        nMaxSlotIndex           0
        bVoltageSupport         7  5.0V 3.0V 1.8V 
        dwProtocols             3  T=0 T=1
        dwDefaultClock       4000
        dwMaxiumumClock      4000
        bNumClockSupported      0
        dwDataRate           9600 bps
        dwMaxDataRate      250000 bps
        bNumDataRatesSupp.      0
        dwMaxIFSD             247
        dwSyncProtocols  00000000 
        dwMechanical     00000000 
        dwFeatures       000102BA
          Auto configuration based on ATR
          Auto voltage selection
          Auto clock change
          Auto baud rate change
          Auto PPS made by CCID
          NAD value other than 0x00 accepted
          TPDU level exchange
        dwMaxCCIDMsgLen       271
        bClassGetResponse      00
        bClassEnvelope         00
        wlcdLayout           none
        bPINSupport             0 
        bMaxCCIDBusySlots       1
      Endpoint Descriptor:
        bLength                 7
        bDescriptorType         5
        bEndpointAddress     0x82  EP 2 IN
        bmAttributes            2
          Transfer Type            Bulk
          Synch Type               None
          Usage Type               Data
        wMaxPacketSize     0x0040  1x 64 bytes
        bInterval               0
      Endpoint Descriptor:
        bLength                 7
        bDescriptorType         5
        bEndpointAddress     0x02  EP 2 OUT
        bmAttributes            2
          Transfer Type            Bulk
          Synch Type               None
          Usage Type               Data
        wMaxPacketSize     0x0040  1x 64 bytes
        bInterval               0
      Endpoint Descriptor:
        bLength                 7
        bDescriptorType         5
        bEndpointAddress     0x86  EP 6 IN
        bmAttributes            3
          Transfer Type            Interrupt
          Synch Type               None
          Usage Type               Data
        wMaxPacketSize     0x0010  1x 16 bytes
        bInterval              32
    Interface Descriptor:
      bLength                 9
      bDescriptorType         4
      bInterfaceNumber        2
      bAlternateSetting       0
      bNumEndpoints           3
      bInterfaceClass        11 Chip/SmartCard
      bInterfaceSubClass      0 
      bInterfaceProtocol      0 
      iInterface              6 
      ChipCard Interface Descriptor:
        bLength                54
        bDescriptorType        33
        bcdCCID              1.01  (Warning: Only accurate for version 1.0)
        nMaxSlotIndex           0
        bVoltageSupport         1  5.0V 
        dwProtocols             3  T=0 T=1
        dwDefaultClock       3580
        dwMaxiumumClock      3580
        bNumClockSupported      1
        dwDataRate           9600 bps
        dwMaxDataRate        9600 bps
        bNumDataRatesSupp.      1
        dwMaxIFSD             254
        dwSyncProtocols  00000000 
        dwMechanical     00000000 
        dwFeatures       000204BA
          Auto configuration based on ATR
          Auto voltage selection
          Auto clock change
          Auto baud rate change
          Auto PPS made by CCID
          Auto IFSD exchange
          Short APDU level exchange
        dwMaxCCIDMsgLen       512
        bClassGetResponse      00
        bClassEnvelope         00
        wlcdLayout           none
        bPINSupport             0 
        bMaxCCIDBusySlots       1
      Endpoint Descriptor:
        bLength                 7
        bDescriptorType         5
        bEndpointAddress     0x83  EP 3 IN
        bmAttributes            2
          Transfer Type            Bulk
          Synch Type               None
          Usage Type               Data
        wMaxPacketSize     0x0040  1x 64 bytes
        bInterval               0
      Endpoint Descriptor:
        bLength                 7
        bDescriptorType         5
        bEndpointAddress     0x03  EP 3 OUT
        bmAttributes            2
          Transfer Type            Bulk
          Synch Type               None
          Usage Type               Data
        wMaxPacketSize     0x0040  1x 64 bytes
        bInterval               0
      Endpoint Descriptor:
        bLength                 7
        bDescriptorType         5
        bEndpointAddress     0x87  EP 7 IN
        bmAttributes            3
          Transfer Type            Interrupt
          Synch Type               None
          Usage Type               Data
        wMaxPacketSize     0x0010  1x 16 bytes
        bInterval              32
    Interface Descriptor:
      bLength                 9
      bDescriptorType         4
      bInterfaceNumber        3
      bAlternateSetting       0
      bNumEndpoints           3
      bInterfaceClass       255 Vendor Specific Class
      bInterfaceSubClass      0 
      bInterfaceProtocol      0 
      iInterface              8 
      ** UNRECOGNIZED:  10 26 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
      Endpoint Descriptor:
        bLength                 7
        bDescriptorType         5
        bEndpointAddress     0x84  EP 4 IN
        bmAttributes            2
          Transfer Type            Bulk
          Synch Type               None
          Usage Type               Data
        wMaxPacketSize     0x0040  1x 64 bytes
        bInterval               0
      Endpoint Descriptor:
        bLength                 7
        bDescriptorType         5
        bEndpointAddress     0x04  EP 4 OUT
        bmAttributes            2
          Transfer Type            Bulk
          Synch Type               None
          Usage Type               Data
        wMaxPacketSize     0x0040  1x 64 bytes
        bInterval               0
      Endpoint Descriptor:
        bLength                 7
        bDescriptorType         5
        bEndpointAddress     0x88  EP 8 IN
        bmAttributes            3
          Transfer Type            Interrupt
          Synch Type               None
          Usage Type               Data
        wMaxPacketSize     0x0010  1x 16 bytes
        bInterval              32
```

The smartcard driver (SafeSign) itself is installed, as the smartcard works with my usb reader. The packages "libccid, pcscd, and libssl0.9.8" are installed properly. The tokenadmin utility does not even show the reader. Any ideas where the problem could be?

Answer (score 1):

The Broadcom with IdProduct 0x5804 should be supported as it is listed [here](https://pcsclite.alioth.debian.org/ccid/shouldwork.html#0x0A5C0x5804) in the "[Should work but untested by me](https://pcsclite.alioth.debian.org/ccid/shouldwork.html)" list.

See also "[Broadcom CCID readers](https://ludovicrousseau.blogspot.fr/2016/08/broadcom-ccid-readers.html)" on my blog and be sure to have the latest firmware upgrades (upgrade the computer from Windows).

Comment: if it "should work" are you suggesting that the problem mentioned in the question has gone away in subsequent versions of the linux-firmware package or something similar?

Comment: The reader "should work". But I do not have enough details to debug the problem. Following the page "How to get support" https://pcsclite.alioth.debian.org/ccid.html#support would help me identify the problem. Disclaimer: I am the author of the CCID driver.